# dpdk-19.11,ixgbe PMD got imissed when up to 8Mpps(decreased 3Mpps),any one have solution or know the reason

Tags: dpdk

using DPDK 17.02 with my custom application, I get to see missed fo 11Mpps. Using 19.11 DPDK it has reduced to 8Mpps. are there compile flags or code changes for ixgbe PMD which has reduced the same.

new updates:
the application arch is rx_cores(3)-->worker cores(16)-->tx cores(2),
when I increased tx cores to 3,it can reach 10M pps,but increased to 4,It didn't take affects any more

Comment: Please explain `netdev` which is PMD in question?

Comment: has been waiting for updates, a decrease in `missed` is good and not bad.

Comment: netdev is the port, use the rte_eth_stats can get  stats.imissed

Comment: can you tell me is it i40e, mlx, please note there is netdev on DPDK Physcial port. only instance is in KNI and TAP. so once again, what is your netdev?

Comment: is a pysical port,Intel Corporation 82599ES 10-Gigabit SFI/SFP+ Network Connection (rev 01)

Comment: thanks for the update, so your question really is `using DPDK 17.02 with my custom application, I get to see missed fo 11Mpps. Using 19.11 DPDK it has reduced to 8Mpps. are there compile flags or code changes for ixgbe PMD which has reduced the same?`. if this is your question please update the question as shared? I can suggest possible causes and possible ways to check.

Answer (score 3):

`imissed` stands for packets missed in HW, due to less number of poll cycles for RX thread. Lower the value better it is. Hence using DPDK 19.11 it is having reduced impact.

reasons for `imissed` to be lower is 19.11 can be

1. better compiler flags
2. better code optimization.
3. assuming you are using static libraries, code logic might be better fitting into the instruction cache.

note: you should really run `profiler` and use `objdump` to decipher this.

reasons for `imissed` in your applications could be the following reasons

1. CPU frequency is in `power save` and not `performance` (impact of not disabling C states in BIOS).
2. The is additional work or sleep added in RX thread loop will prevent rx_burst been invoked frequently
3. RSS is enabled, but traffic send to DPDK port is falling on 1 queue only. In case of too many RX queues like 16, this leads to increase delay to pick packet from the relevant queue.
4. iF RX thread is feeding worker cores based on flow id, there could be retries if RING full scenarios leading to loss of rx_burst.

If testpmd or example/skeleton or example/l2fwd is not having imissed. then here are my suggestions to debug your applciation.

1. try sending RX-TX from single-core
2. set power governed from powersave to performance.
3. ensure you are running the core threads on isolated cores.

Comment: were you able to further reduce the missed?